# Problem with ggplot ? finding original and current world records in mario

Tags: r

I HAD A PROBLEM CODING THIS GRAPH WITH GGPLOT IN R. THOUGHT SOMEBODY WOULD BE ABLE TO HELP ME HERE.
THE MAIN PROBLEM IS FINDING THE ORIGINAL AND CURRENT WORLD RECORDS FROM THE DATASET
THE LINK TO THE DATASET IT BELOW
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1olmDVa0Ku01LQrkpC_MkGq7_wFO8gLPQ/view?usp=sharing

THANKS
this is the plot i need to code ->
[PLOT IN R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKyyV.png)

Comment: Certainly, someone could help you here, if you shared at least some of your data using the dput function and showed us your code, which has been causing you problems so far.

Comment: the data is in the drive link

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

fLm = function(data) lm(time~date, data)

dPradict = function(data){
  model = data$model[[1]]
  data = data$data[[1]]
  dfFirstLast = data %>% arrange(date) %>% slice_head() %>%
    bind_rows(data %>% arrange(date) %>% slice_tail()) %>%
    select(date, time)
  tibble(
    x = c("Orginal", "Current") %>% fct_inorder(),
    time = c(predict(model, dfFirstLast)[1],
             predict(model, dfFirstLast)[2])
  )
}

df = read_csv("records.csv", show_col_types = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(track = track %>% fct_relevel("Banshee Boardwalk")) %>% 
  group_by(track) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~fLm(.x))) %>% 
  group_modify(~dPradict(.x))


df4 = df %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(x=="Current") %>% 
  arrange(desc(time)) %>% 
  slice_head(n=4)


df %>% ggplot(aes(as.numeric(x), time, color=track))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(size=3)+
  geom_label(aes(as.numeric(x), time, label=track), data = df4, hjust=-.1)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1, 2), name="WR",
                     labels=c("Orginal", "Current"),
                     limits=c(0.8,2.2))+
  labs(title = "Comparing the orginal and current WR for tree lap and no shortcut races")
```

[image]